# Visual Studio write to Office 365 word

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, office365, office-interop, com-interop

I created an app (in visual studio 2015 and .net) that writes to Word 2013 (it creates the word document, fills in paragraphs of text, tables, numbers, etc... through bookmarks) it's been working great but now my company upgraded office to the 365 version, and I'm getting errors communicating with the 365 version of word.

I've added all the right references to my project :

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Microsoft.Office.core
Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library

but I'm getting the following error :

```
COMException was unhandled

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

My code is very simple, the error happens on **Dim appWord As New Word.Application**

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Private Sub word_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles word.Click

**Dim appWord As New Word.Application**
Dim docWord As New Word.Document


docWord = appWord.Documents.Add("s:\direct\ph1English.docx")
appWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

I'm not sure what's changed in this new version of Office, I don't have a problem buying extensions or whatever to make it work, I just have no clue what's needed to get my app to communicate with word again,

I really appreciate any help you can offer

Thank you,

Fred

I've tried adding all the needed references

Comment: There's no 365 version of Word. Either Word is installed locally or not. If it is, you need to use the *correct* version of the interop library. 2013 is way, way too old and newer Word versions probably don't install `Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library` by default.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply, yes I know it's not 365, I just meant it's bundled in the 365 version, the real version of word is (2402). The reference Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library is installed and I added it as a reference to my project but it's not working